# Advice required to insert one string into another once obtaining text from clipboard

Tags: c++, string, winapi, clipboard, editcontrol

### INTRODUCTION AND RELEVANT INFORMATION:

I have an `edit control` that needs to accept only signed decimal numbers ( something like `-12.35` ).

I have decided to implement this via `subclassing`.

The `WM_CHAR` handler seems to works well, and I need to handle several other messages to completely protect user from entering invalid text. One such message is `WM_PASTE`.

So far I was able to properly get the text from the `clipboard` and to discard or pass the message depending if the copied string is indeed decimal number.

Edit control has limited input to 12 characters. This is done via `EM_SETLIMITTEXT` message.

I use `pure Winapi` and `C++`. No libraries like `boost` etc are allowed.

### PROBLEM:

So far I test the case where edit control is empty and I discard pasting if the content is invalid. However, user can select a portion of the text in the edit control and then perform pasting. Something like this ( grey characters represent selection ):

*Text in edit control:* 123`456`78.9

*Clipboard text :* -1A

The resulting string, if I would allow pasting, would be 123-1A78.9 which is invalid format.

This is the part I need help with:

My parsing properly recognizes valid format but I do not know how to properly merge two strings into one so I could test it.

### QUESTIONS:

1. How can I properly form the resulting string from pasting so I can test its validity ?
2. Is there a function that can do the validity test for me ( **it should be locale aware!** ) ?

Note: I do not mind parsing the text myself but why "reinventing the wheel" if there is no need for it?

### MY EFFORTS TO SOLVE THIS:

1. Browsing through Internet I found many `std::` functions that concatenate/cut off/ etc string but none of them seem to satisfy my needs for forming the resulting string. The closest thing I found was `string:: insert(...)` but I do not know how to use it.
2. As for the second question, I found `std:: strtod` by browsing through *StackOverflow* questions and it seems that it can be used to check the validity of the string. And it seems that it is locale aware as well, but I am not sure if it is what I seek.

To keep this post as brief as possible I provide the link to [this question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22263612/properly-handle-wm-paste-in-subclass-procedure) that has relevant code snippets.

Thank you for your time and help.

If further info is required I will update the post.

Best regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
case WM_PASTE:
{
    std::wstring cbtext;

    if( !OpenClipboard(hwnd) ) // open clipboard
        return 0;

    // get clipboard data
    HANDLE hClipboardData = GetClipboardData(CF_UNICODETEXT);
    if( hClipboardData )
    {
        // Call GlobalLock so that to retrieve a pointer
        // to the data associated with the handle returned
        // from GetClipboardData.

        cbtext = (LPWSTR) GlobalLock(hClipboardData);

        // Unlock the global memory.
        GlobalUnlock(hClipboardData);
    }

    // Finally, when finished I simply close the Clipboard
    // which has the effect of unlocking it so that other
    // applications can examine or modify its contents.

    CloseClipboard();

    if (cbtext.empty())
        return 0;

    // format the new text with the clipboard data inserted as needed

    int len = GetWindowTextLengthW(hwnd);
    std::wstring newtext(len, 0);
    if (len > 0)
        GetWindowTextW(hWnd, &newtext[0], len);

    DWORD start, end;
    SendMessageW(hwnd, EM_GETSEL, (WPARAM)&start, (LPARAM)&end);

    if (end > start)
        newtext.replace(start, end-start, cbtext);
    else
        newtext.insert(start, cbtext);

    // parse the new text for validity

    // code for parsing text 
    if( IsTextValid )
        SetWindowTextW( hwnd, newtext.c_str() );

    return 0;
}
```